# iOS. Interface orientation on launch

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation, uiwindow, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app that supports both portrait and landscape.
So in Info.plist / Project Settings I specify both orientations.

In my UIViewController I override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to return `.landscape`.

But when I launch my app it is first displayed in portrait mode (with wrecked layout), and then unpleasant animation rotates it to landscape (see video).

I also tried overriding `application(_, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window)` with the same result.

Sample project [demonstrating](https://s3.amazonaws.com/glazba/orientation_issue_sample.gif) the issue:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/glazba/OrientationTest.zip

[image: Orientation issue video]

Answer (score 1):

Adding **UIInterfaceOrientation** in Info.plist and setting it to landscape seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it does, but it disables portrait orientation entirely, despite `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in UIViewController :(

Comment: I can set `.landscape` in .plist and return `.all` in UIApplicationDelegate, but it will result in the same weird animation when launching in portrait :(